# Running a command with Ampersand kills the process after next command

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run a process in background. I ran the following command:

```
sudo gitlab-runner run latex >> gitlab-runner1.log 2>&1 &
```

This gives me the pid of the process that is running in background, but when I press enter again, I get the following output on the screen:

```
[3]+  Stopped                 sudo gitlab-runner run latex >> gitlab-runner1.log 2>&1
```

Is there something wrong with my command? How do I run this gitlab runner command in background?

Comment: All you are doing is running `gitlab-runner run latex` with `sudo` and then redirecting both `stdin` and `stderr` to append to `gitlab-runner1.log` and then you background the whole thing with `&`. There is nothing there to make it stop unless `gitlab-runner run latex` stopped on its own. Run without `&` and also check the end of `gitlab-runner1.log` for hints on why it croaked.

Comment: I don't know what is going on here, but technically speaking, the background process received a _SIGSTOP_. This could happen if you would press Control-Z, but not if you just press enter.  I don't know gitlab-runner, but I would run it for test without any redirection. Also, I would try to run it with `</dev/null`. If you do so, does the _stopped_ occur immediately?

Comment: Can you share processes running on your terminal, when the sudo is "stopped" ? `ps -f`